# Mask all sub page requests to parent page

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, vuejs2

I have a Wordpress website with one page using Vuejs to display some items.

This page is routed to /hire within wordpress which is where the Vuejs file is loaded. I am displaying 'subpages' via Vuejs currently like this: /hire/#cameras - how can I remove the # so my urls look like /hire/cameras

I have tried a few things in .htaccess but I keep getting a 404 with everything I try...

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#RewriteRule ^hire/([^/]+)/?$ hire [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(hire/)./$ /hire

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working with the following function:

```
function hire_page_rewrite() {
  add_rewrite_rule( '^hire\/(.*)\/?', "index.php?page_id=7", 'top' );
}
add_action('init', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\hire_page_rewrite');
```